# Duvida sobre Listener para JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Alguém saberia me dizer algum Listener para quando eu selecionar um item no JComboBox ele me da um aviso por exemplo. Lembrando que quando eu abro meu componente(JFrame) eu seto itens lá dentro pelo banco então não pode cair no Listener.

Vamos lá explicando melhor o meu projeto

O botão "..." abre a janela de cadastro de modalidade, toda vez que eu cadastro uma modalidade eu atualizado o combo box "modalidade" que no momento está com o registro "dança" toda vez que eu escolho uma modalidade no meu combobox ele vai abrir uma nova janela para cadastrar a mensalidade. Então como eu faço para carregar meu combobox na hora que eu abrir minha aplicação sem ativar o listener e como eu atualizo o combobox sem ativar o listener? Eu quero que o listener só seja ativado quando o usuario seleciona um item da lista, mas pelo que parece o comando "combobox.addItem("Teste");" ativa o listener na hora de atualizar. Alguma sugestão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método utilizado para atualizar o Combobox quando eu cadastro uma modalidade ou quando eu apenas abro meu sistema.

```
public void setModalidade() {
    try {
        this.cboModalidade.removeAllItems();

        this.listaModalidade = new ArrayList<Modalidade>(new ModalidadeDAO().listaTodos());

        int i = 0;
        for(Modalidade modalidade : listaModalidade) {
            this.cboModalidade.addItem(modalidade.getTituloModalidade());
            if(this.modalidade.getTituloModalidade().equalsIgnoreCase(modalidade.getTituloModalidade())) {
                this.cboModalidade.setSelectedIndex(i);                 
            }
            i++;
        }

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Esse é os listener que utilizo ou que já utilizei para tentar.

```
    JCombobox combobox = new JCombobox<>();
combobox.addActionListener(this); //<-- já tentei esse

combobox.addItemListener(this); //<-- Estou usando esse mas a função "combobox.addItem("Teste"); que utilizou para atualizar meu combobox ativa o ActionListener e o ItemListener
```

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim, tem algum item em especial que deve ativar o aviso? O que o banco de dados tem a ver com o Listener?

Comment: Acredito que sua pergunta está um pouco confusa... Tente ser mais claro...

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você quer colocar um listener em um evento que seja disparado quando o usuário seleciona um item da combo. O que você está usando agora para fazer isso está sendo disparado quando o método `addItem` é chamado. É isso? Talvez fique mais claro se você colocar o código referente ao listener que está usando, ou pelo menos indicar qual o nome do evento em que você associou o listener.

Comment: " O que você está usando agora para fazer isso está sendo disparado quando o método addItem é chamado". É exatamente isso que está acontencendo, vou postar o código para talvez melhorar o entendimento, mas programa já esta um tanto quando complexo, mas vamos lá

Answer (score 1):

É pessoal a unica solução que eu encontrei foi.

```
public void setModalidade() {
        this.cboModalidade.removeActionListener(this); //<-- Quando eu vou setar o combobox com dados eu desativo o ActionListener
        try {
            this.cboModalidade.removeAllItems();

            this.listaModalidade = new ArrayList<Modalidade>(new ModalidadeDAO().listaTodos());

            int i = 0;
            for(Modalidade modalidade : listaModalidade) {
                this.cboModalidade.addItem(modalidade.getTituloModalidade());
                if(this.modalidade.getTituloModalidade().equalsIgnoreCase(modalidade.getTituloModalidade())) {
                    this.cboModalidade.addActionListener(this); //<-- quando eu realizo o cadastro de uma nova modalidade e dou um refresh no meu combobox eu ativo o Actionlister para ele seleciona o id da modalidade que acabei de cadastrar e automaticamente abrir a janela para inserir e mensalidade.
                    this.cboModalidade.setSelectedIndex(i);                 
                }
                i++;
            }

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.cboModalidade.addActionListener(this); //<-- Quando termina de setar o combobox eu ativo o Actionlistener novamente
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo o ItemListenner e funciona.

Faço da seguinte forma.

```
combobox.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getStateChange() == java.awt.event.ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
             //o tratamento a esse evento aqui.
            //ele dispara duas vezes a cada item selecionado, 
            //um para o que foi DESELECTED e outro para o SELECTED por isso a comparação.

        }

   } 

}
```

espero ser isso que procura e ter ajudado.